# Passing cookie to Firefox for Android browser

Tags: java, android, firefox, android-intent, cookies

I have a method that executes a post request on my server, and when successful my server returns a cookie

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", uname));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", passwd));
            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            try {
                  response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                  List<Cookie> cookiejar = ((AbstractHttpClient) httpclient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
                  for (Cookie c : cookiejar)
                  {
                      cookiename=c.getName();
                      coo = c.getValue(); 

                  }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Till here everything works fine, now after getting the cookie I want to send it to Firefox. I have tried the following but it does not seem to be working.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null);

        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("org.mozilla.firefox", "org.mozilla.firefox.App"));
        intent.setAction("org.mozilla.gecko.BOOKMARK");
        //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.putExtra("args", "--url=" + url1 );
        intent.putExtra("args", "--Cookie" + coo );
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(url1));
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putBoolean("new_window", true); //sets new window
        intent.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Can someone please help me find out where am going wrong?

Comment: Can you give a link to the firefox documentation for `intent.putExtra("args", "--url=" + url1 );   intent.putExtra("args", "--Cookie" + coo );` ? Further you cannot have twice a `putExtra() for "args"' Only the last one will remain as far as i know.

Comment: found out that this is not possible, firefox does not allow cookies to inserted directly as mentioned above since it may lead to security vulnerabilities. thanks all.